# Estimating the Frobenius norm of $A^{-1} - I$ using the Frobenius norm of $A - I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

I am solving the following problem:

> Fix $0<\varepsilon<1$ and suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is symmetric and nonsingular. Show that if $\|A-I\|_F \geq \varepsilon$, then $\left\|A^{-1}-I\right\|_F \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

---

Here is my attempt:
Since $A$ is real and symmetric,
$$
\|A\|_F= \sqrt{\text{trace}(A^* A)} = \sqrt{\text{trace}(A^T A)}  = \sqrt{\text{trace}(A^2)} .
$$
Hence, we have
$$
\|A - I\|_F^2= (a_{11} - 1)^2 + \cdots + (a_{mm} - 1)^2 \geq \varepsilon.
$$

But, I cannot go further. Could you give me any hint about this problem?

Comment: Hint: Since $A$ is real and symmetric, both norms can be written explicitly in terms of the eiganvalues of $A$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your comment. I revised the title.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you for your comment. I am trying again. As you said, I used the diagonalization of $A$, and could rewrite the norm in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_m$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$. We have,
\begin{align*}
\|A^{-1} - I\|_{F}^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^m \left(\frac{1}{\lambda_i} - 1 \right)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{(\lambda_i - 1)^2}{\lambda_i^2}.
\end{align*}
If for some $j$, $|\lambda_j| \geq 2$, then, $\displaystyle \|A^{-1} - I\|_{F}^2 \geq \frac{(\lambda_j - 1)^2}{\lambda_j^2} \geq \frac{1}{4} \geq \frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}$ as $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. This implies $\|A^{-1} - I\|_{F} \geq \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. If no such $j$ exists, then it implies that $|\lambda_i| \leq 2$ for all $i = 1, 2,\dots, m$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\|A^{-1} - I\|_{F}^2  = \sum_{i = 1}^m \frac{(\lambda_i - 1)^2}{\lambda_i^2} \geq \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i = 1}^m {(\lambda_i - 1)^2} \geq \frac{1}{4} \|A - I\|_F^2.
\end{align*}
This implies $\|A^{-1} - I\|_{F} \geq \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ since $\|A - I\|_F \geq \varepsilon$.

Comment: Wow! I appreciate your comment. I fully understood the point. I tried to solve this problem for a long time. Now, I got the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I think you are assuming that all eigenvalues are positive. This breaks your inequality in the second case. Here we only have that $\lambda$'s are real and nonzero

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks for pointing it out. The solution works just fine if we apply the arguments to the magnitude of the eigenvalues instead of the eigenvalues themselves. I have edited the solution to reflect that.